# Couldn't read error message : AngularJS - Spring 4

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to develop a Web application using AngularJS + Spring4.

What i want to do:

1.If http request is success, needs to send response data as JSON
2.In case of an exception, needs to send custom error message (will be shown to the user in alert box)

Spring controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadAllUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String loadAllUsers(@RequestBody String paramsJsonStr,ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

String responseJSONStr = null;
ResponseJSON responseJSON = new ResponseJSON(); //Custom class for sending response data 

try {
    .....
    .....
    List<User> users = this.loadAllUsers();
    responseJSON.setIsSuccessful(true);
    responseJSON.setData(schemas);
    responseJSONStr = JSONUtilities.toJson(responseJSON);
}catch (CustomException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    response.sendError(e.getErrorCode(), e.getErrorMessage());
}

   return responseJSONStr;
}
```

AngularJs controller:

```
$http.post("loadAllUsers",{})
.success(function(data){
    console.log('success handler');
    console.log(data);
})
.error(function(error) {
    console.log('error handler');
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.data);
    console.log(error.statusText );
    console.log(error.headers);
    console.log(error.config);
})
```

Problem :
      Not able to read error message , but able to read the success data.

when i print the error in console am getting this HTML tags:

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Invalid input.</body></html>
```

How to parse this error message in AngularJS ? Is this the correct way to send error message from spring ??

If i send the error message also in same JSON "responseJSONStr", it'll be processes in success handler of the AngularJS as response will be considered as success in this case.

Any guidance will be very helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The success path do this JSONUtilities.toJson(responseJSON); -> to JSON what do thi stuff do for you? response.sendError(e.getErrorCode(), e.getErrorMessage()); i.e. one scenario converts your reponse to Json whereas the other seems not do do it, or

Comment: 1.That will give me a Json string.  2. Ya i want to send the error message to UI and show it to the user. If i send that error message in same  "responseJSONStr" it will come to success block in AngularJs , so i wrote like that..

Comment: @7663233 Is there any way where we can tell the AngularJS to read the http status from the " responseJSONStr" JSON which am sending from server ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone in future tried to do the same this may help.. To achieve this, instead of using "response.sendError" a failure status code can be set using "response.setStatus" and error message can be set in responseJSON with isSuccessful as "false" as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadAllUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String loadAllUsers(@RequestBody String paramsJsonStr,ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

String responseJSONStr = null;
ResponseJSON responseJSON = new ResponseJSON(); //Custom class for sending response data 

try {
     .....
     .....
     List<User> users = this.loadAllUsers();
     responseJSON.setIsSuccessful(true);
     responseJSON.setData(schemas);
}catch (CustomException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     response.setStatus(e.getErrorCode()); //http failure status code as per respective error
     responseJSON.setIsSuccessful(false);
     responseJSON.setMessage(e.getErrorMessage());
}

 responseJSONStr = JSONUtilities.toJson(responseJSON);
 return responseJSONStr;
}
```